# I can't handle any data in background fetch

Tags: flutter, background-fetch

I'm trying get data from `sqflite` once and faced issue and I can't solved it now I'm trying `SharedPreferences` it's give me that error

**my main.dart code is**

```
void headlessTask(bg.HeadlessEvent headlessEvent) async {
  print('[--=-=-=-===--==--=-==--=-=-=-= HeadlessTask]: $headlessEvent');
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String battery_save_power_mode = prefs.getString('battery_save_power_mode');
  print('[[[battery_save_power_mode $battery_save_power_mode]]]');

}


void main() async {

  runApp( MyApp());

  // Register your headlessTask:
  bg.BackgroundGeolocation.registerHeadlessTask(headlessTask);

}
```

**the error is**

> E/flutter (13424): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)

Comment: Where did you put the headlessTask function in? Doesn't look like it's in the same class.

Comment: @FadhliS the headlessTask() and main() all in main.dart page

Comment: Have you correctly import the SharedPreferences package? It seems to be an error in the package itself. It is trying to call the method getAll which is not available.

Comment: @FadhliS yes I imported it I have recored what happened maybe there is wrong with my .
youtube.com/watch?v=zuA4BmTjt8w

Comment: it's work as good when app is opened but when I terminated it it's give me this error

Comment: same here..Have you fixed?

Comment: @JohnJoe yes it's due to package not support android embedding 2

Comment: @MahmoudNiypoo sharedPreferences package?